# How to feature detect rel="prefetch"

Tags: javascript, html

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch) resource *prefteching* `<link rel="prefetch" href="some-resource" />` is only available on some browsers.

How can I feature detect this in JavaScript ? In the example below, how to have the value of `isPrefecthSupported`

```
if(isPrefecthSupported) {
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'prefetch');
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(link);
} else {
   //try something else...
}
```

Comment: Why bother, simply set it and those how can will use it ... or is there something else you need?

Comment: @LGSon I'll use a fallback otherwise if prefetch is not supported.

Comment: You could always fallback anyway, if the browser supports the prefetch then it should already be fetched by the time your fallback kicks in, so will be cached and the fallback won't really do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally managed to feature detect it. There are edge cases (when `DomTokenList.supports` isn't supported either) but you can do :

```js
var support = function support(feature){
    var fakeLink = document.createElement('link');
    try {
        if(fakeLink.relList && _.isFunction(fakeLink.relList.supports)){
            return  fakeLink.relList.supports(feature);
        }
    } catch(err){
        return false;
    }
};
var isPrefetchSupported = support('prefetch');
var isPreloadSupported = support('preload');
```